# How do I restrict User Config GPO Software Installation on certain computers?

Tags: windows-10, installation, group-policy, windows-installer

I have a custom piece of software at my business that I'm trying to install using a GPO. I have it currently set under Computer Configuration > Software Installation. And this works well, but the users at our business can go DAYS without restarting their computers. This could lead to it being days before getting the initial installation and/or subsequent installs afterwards. *The only workaround for this I found is to use a script to force restart all applicable computers.*

Using the User Configuration > Software Installation would guarantee that the software would be installed/updated within 2 hours max, but I have a little hitch with this. I don't want the program to be installed/run on certain computers. (Mainly Servers)

I'm wanting to know if there's a way to use the User Policy Software Installation mechanism, but restrict it from installing if applicable users are on a specific computer?

Comment: Seems like the simple solution is to have a PowerShell script that is ran daily that determines if the amount of time since a last reboot has happened exceeds the number of days you want to allow a machine NOT to be rebooted.  This way you can exclude the servers from even running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're looking for is *Loopback Processing*. It'll take a User Configuration setting, and allow it to be applied to the OU of Computer objects instead of users.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/loopback-processing-of-group-policy

> Group Policy applies to the user or computer in a manner that depends on where both the user and the computer objects are located in Active Directory. In some cases, users may need policy applied to them based on the location of the computer object alone. You can use the Group Policy loopback feature to apply Group Policy Objects (GPOs) that depend only on which computer the user signs in to.

https://www.mustbegeek.com/how-to-enable-gpo-loopback-processing/